# Problem passing argument in hash table from global context to a module

Tags: scoping, hashing

[image: Mathematica graphics]

I was experimenting with passing arguments via a hash table to a module. Found a very strange result. When I pass a function to be plotted inside the module, it comes out empty.

Yet all argument passed look correct when printing them.

This seems like a scope problem? But I am passing everything to the module?

I just can't exactly know what is going on. A small example will show the problem.

The caller does this

```
ClearAll[x,y];
ode["f"]    =  Cos[x] (*function to plot*)
ode["xmin"] = -Pi;
ode["xmax"] = Pi;
ode["x"]    = x; (*symbol*)
makePlot[ode]
```

And the module just reads the input from the hash table and calls plot.

```
makePlot[ode_]:=Module[{p,f,x,xmin,xmax},
f     = ode["f"];
xmin  = ode["xmin"];
xmax  = ode["xmax"];
x     = ode["x"];

(*print to verify*)
Print[InputForm[f]];
Print[InputForm[xmin]];
Print[InputForm[xmax]];
Print[InputForm[x]];

p = Plot[f,{x,xmin,xmax}];
Print[p] (*this prints only the frame and with no actual graphics*)
]
```

Here is screen shot of the print on console

[image: Mathematica graphics]

This problem only affects the plot commands. All other computation using this passing method work fine. I've been using this method for few days with no problems. It is only graphics come out empty.

I tried adding `Evaluate` to the plot, but that had no effect.

This works OK, if all is done on global level

```
ClearAll[x, y];

ode["f"] = Cos[x];
ode["xmin"] = -Pi;
ode["xmax"] = Pi;
ode["x"] = x;

f    = ode["f"];
xmin = ode["xmin"];
xmax = ode["xmax"];
x    = ode["x"];

p = Plot[f, {x, xmin, xmax}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The question is, why it does not work inside a module? And what does one need to make it work inside a module?

Comment: use `p = Plot[f, Evaluate@{x, xmin, xmax}]` in place of `p = Plot[f, {x, xmin, xmax}]`?

Comment: @kglr I tried `Evaluate@f` but did not try `Evaluate@{x, xmin, xmax}`. Adding the second one made it work! thanks. Even though I do not understand why, but it works :)

Comment: .. or `p = With[{x1 = x, xmin1 = xmin, xmax1 = xmax}, 
 Plot[f, {x1, xmin1, xmax1}]]`

Comment: it is the old `HoldAll` thing.

Comment: @kglr, But it works in global context, without using `Evaluate@` on both. `Evaluate` is needed if there is a function that needs to be evaluated and its value needs to be used by `Plot`. But here I do not see why it is needed. But any way, thanks, your method made it work, which is the important thing.

Comment: Nasser, good point.

Comment: It doesn't work inside of the module, because the `Module` produces an `x` variable with a different name (like `x$2412`). The function `f` still depends on the global `x` but the plot iterator goes over this localized version of `x`. So you're basically plotting something like `Plot[Cos[x], {x$2412, -1, 1}]`. This is why you need to make sure `x$2412` evaluates to `x` first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wrapping the iterator in `Plot` with `Evaluate`, i.e. using

```
p = Plot[f, Evaluate@{x, xmin, xmax}]
```

instead of `p = Plot[f, {x, xmin, xmax}]` fixes the problem:

```
makePlot[ode]
```

[image]